# Copy columns from workbook, paste in second sheet of second workbook, openPyXL

Tags: python, excel, copy-paste, openpyxl

I'm new to openpyxl and am developing a tool that requires copying & pasting columns.

I have a folder containing two sets of excel files. I need the script to iterate through the files, find the ones that are named "GenLU_xx" (xx represents name of a place such as Calgary) and copy Columns C & E (3 & 5). It then needs to find the corresponding file which is named as "LU_Summary_xx" (xx again represents name of place such as Calgary) and paste the copied columns to the second sheet of that workbook. It needs to match GenLU_Calgary with LUZ_Summary_Calgary and so forth for all the files. So far I have not been able to figure out code for copying and pasting columns and the seemingly double iteration is confusing me. My python skills are beginner although I'm usually able to figure out code by looking at examples. In this case I'm having some trouble locating sample code. Just started using openpyxl. I have completed the script except for the parts pertaining to excel. Hopefully someone can help out. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: New to StackOverflow as well so not sure why I got -2. Maybe due to lack of any code?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    import os, openpyxl, glob
from openpyxl import Workbook
Tables = r"path"
os.chdir(Tables)
for file in glob.glob ("LUZ*"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb.active
    ws ["G1"] = "GEN_LU_ZN"
    wb.create_sheet(title="Sheet2")
    wb.save(file)
```

This just adds a value to G1 of every file starting with LUZ and creates a second sheet.

As I mentioned previously, I have yet to even figure out the code for copying the values of an entire column.

I am thinking I could iterate through all files starting with "GenLU*" using glob and then store the values of Columns 3 & 5 but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to access values for columns. I do not have a range of rows as each workbook will have a different number of rows for the two columns.

EDIT 2: I am able to access cell values for a particular column using this code:

```
for file in glob.glob ("GenLU_Airdrie*"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, use_iterators=True)
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows ('C1:C200'):
        for cell in row:
            values = cell.value
            print values
```

However I'm not sure how I would go about 'pasting' these values in column A of the other sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really do want to work with columns then you can use the `.columns` property when reading files.

To copy the values from one sheet to another you just assign them. The following will copy the value of A1 from one worksheet to another.

```
ws1 = wb1.active
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2['A1'] = ws1['A1'].value
```

To copy column D code could look something like this

```
col_d = ws1.columns[3] # 0-indexing
for idx, cell in enumerate(col_d, 1):
    ws.cell(row=idx, col=4).value = cell.value #1-indexing
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I will comment once I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: @Charlie: Is it possible to keep the same format for new column.

Answer (score 6):

Charlie's code worked for me by changing 'col=4' to 'column=4' using openpyxl-2.3.3

```
ws.cell(row=idx, column=4).value = cell.value
```

Comment: Then this should be a comment to Charlie's answer

Comment: Which one can do with 50 reputations :)

Comment: Ah. Yes. OK - I'll shut up, in that case.

Comment: No, @SiHa is right, this *still* should be a comment, because it completely relies on some other post.  Just because you can't comment everywhere yet doesn't mean you are thereby allowed to post comments as answers.  Better options are to **a)** if the other answer is actually incorrect, you can edit it to make the correction (write a clear explanatory edit summary), or **b)** include the entirety of what answers the question here (*with attribution*) but highlighting your correction.